# Visual Studio 2012 + NUnit unit test integration

Tags: tools, visualstudio, nunit

I am having a problem with integration my NUnit test integration.

I have installed the test adapter for NUnit and also made sure that the extension is enabled, but no test are shown in the test explorer still.

I have already tried to add everything named NUnit from the package manager to my projects, but still no results in the test explorer.

My tests work fine with the outern NUnit program, but just won't integrate to Visual Studio 2012. Any ideas how to solve this? Maybe there is a more detailed documentation how to set up this than the one on the NUnit adapter's site?

Comment: My experience with the visual studio plugin was not very good even after I got it set up.  It crashed frequently and wasn't very reliable.  IF you have the outer NUnit program working, I would suggest continuing to use it.  The only thing that was a little bit annoying was having to go in and attach to the nunit process manually each time you wanted to debug, but overall it was a much better experience than the VS plugin.

Comment: @SamWoods - Thanks for the tipp. NUnit works fine for me. The problem is that I would like to make the tests run atomatically on build. This way I could spot any broken test much earlier.

Comment: You can execute nunit-console.exe from command line, a quick Google search will give you instructions how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Visual Studio Express?
If so, perhaps the workaround described in this SO thread will work for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348613/nunit-runners-via-nuget-on-visual-studio-2012-express-doesnt-work

Edit:
The selected answer, which reveals the limitation of Visual Studio Express + Nunit

```
As I've found out Visual Studio Express does not support project extensions (forbidden and disabled by Microsoft)
```

A subsequent answer to the same question describes how to implement (instructions and code) a workaround via adding and configuring the nunit-console-runner in your test assembly.

Comment: Typically, 'link only' answers are discouraged. Would you consider digesting the information on the link and breaking it down here?